# $\sigma(T(X)) = \sigma(X) \iff T$ is bijective

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, measurable-functions

Consider the following claim:

> Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{M})$, $(\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{N})$ and $(\mathcal{Z},\mathcal{O})$ be measurable spaces, and let $f \colon \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ and $g \colon \mathcal{Y} \to \mathcal{Z}$ be measurable functions. Then $\sigma(g \circ f) = \sigma(f)$ if and only if $g$ is bijective, where $\sigma(g \circ f) = (g \circ f)^{-1}(\mathcal{O}) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(\mathcal{O}))$ and $\sigma(f) = f^{-1}(\mathcal{N})$.

This is false: for the “if” part of the statement, just consider $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y} = \mathcal{Z}$, $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{N}$, $\mathcal{O} = \{ \emptyset, \mathcal{X} \}$ and $f = g = \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{X}}$.

I was going through Shao’s *Mathematical Statistics*, and on page 100 it is claimed that if $X$ is a random vector ($\mathbb{R}^{n}-$valued) and $T(X)$ is a statistic (which to my understanding means that $T$ is a measurable function from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, both endowed with the Borel $\sigma-$algebra), then $\sigma(T(X)) = \sigma(X)$ if and only if $T$ is bijective. What makes this statement true, when the previous was not?

Comment: The second one is also wrong. Perhaps the author wants to say that $\sigma((T(X))=\sigma (X)$ **for every $X$** iff $T$ is bijective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A measurable bijection between standard Borel spaces is a [Borel isomorphism](https://books.google.nl/books?id=WR3SBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=classical+descriptive+set+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjK_e2g8obrAhXBDuwKHV-jCU4Q6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%20Corollary%2015.2&f=false). Therefore,
$$
\sigma(T(X))=X^{-1}(T^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m)))=X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))=\sigma(X).
$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!