# Generated $\sigma$-algebra of $h(X_1,..,X_n)$ where $h$ is one-to-one.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to show that $\mathbb{E}[X|X_1,..x_n]=\mathbb{E}[X|h(X_1,..X_n)]$ where $h:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is one-to-one. My initial plan was to show that $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)=\sigma(h(X_1,..X_n))$ but I can only show that $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)\supseteq \sigma(h(X_1,..X_n))$. Any ideas?

Comment: You did not even mention measurability of $h$. I think something more than  measurability and injectivity of $h$ is needed for this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781898/sigmatx-sigmax-if-and-only-if-t-is-bijective